# compareTo: how to return a boolean?

Tags: java

I am told that compareTo has to return an int...not Boolean.
For example:

Returns

0 if a equal b
-1 if a < b
+1 if a > b

I am slightly confused by that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public int compareTo(Cheese anotherCheese)
   throws ClassCastException
   {
       if (!(anotherCheese instanceof Cheese))
            throw new ClassCastException("A Cheese object expected.");

       if(getCheeseType().compareTo(anotherCheese.getCheeseType()))
            return -1;
       else if (getCheeseType().compareTo(anotherCheese.getCheeseType()))
            return 1;
       else
            return cheesePrice > anotherCheese.getCheesePrice();
   }
```

When I compile, I get the error messages saying:

incompatible types
`if(getCheeseType().compareTo(anotherCheese.getCheeseType()))`
incompatible types
`else if (getCheeseType().compareTo(anotherCheese.getCheeseType()))`
incompatible types
`return cheesePrice > anotherCheese.getCheesePrice();`

Answer (score 4):

`compareTo` does indeed return an `int`, not a `boolean`. You get those compile errors because of that. Inside an `if` statement, you must put a `boolean`.

So instead of

`if(getCheeseType().compareTo(anotherCheese.getCheeseType()))`

write

`if(getCheeseType().compareTo(anotherCheese.getCheeseType()) < 0)`

Answer (score 0):

just do

```
return getCheeseType().compareTo(anotherCheese.getCheeseType());
```

if you want to also compare by price then do

```
if(getCheeseType().compareTo(anotherCheese.getCheeseType())!=0)
    return getCheeseType().compareTo(anotherCheese.getCheeseType());
//cheeseTypes are equal
if(cheesePrice < anotherCheese.getCheesePrice())
    return -1;
else if (cheesePrice > anotherCheese.getCheesePrice())
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   // Order by type.
   int delta = getCheeseType().compareTo(anotherCheese.getCheeseType());
   if (delta != 0) { return delta; }
   // If of the same type, order by price.
   if (cheesePrice < anotherCheese.getCheesePrice()) { return -1; }
   if (cheesePrice > anotherCheese.getCheesePrice()) { return 1; }
   return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes `compareTo` method will return int type, not a `boolean`. But you are using `getCheeseType().compareTo(anotherCheese.getCheeseType())` in if loop, which will leads to compile time errors. change like this.

```
public int compareTo(Cheese anotherCheese)
   throws ClassCastException
   {
       if (!(anotherCheese instanceof Cheese))
            throw new ClassCastException("A Cheese object expected.");

       else return getCheeseType().compareTo(anotherCheese.getCheeseType()))

   }
```